# C# Task Control Flow Logic Not Operating Correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form application with a button that triggers the following action:

```
private async void timeStampDocuments_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await PerformTask(TimeStampPdfs());
}
```

The `PerformTask` method is as follows:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task PerformTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
{
    if(documentsView.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch(System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        progressBar.Text = string.Empty;
        Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please select at least one document.");
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if the condition is false (`documentsView.CheckedItemsCount` is equal to 0), the task still executes. However, once the task finishes, a MessageBox pops up saying "Please select at least one document."

If it helps, the `TimeStampPdfs` method is:

```
private System.Threading.Tasks.Task TimeStampPdfs() => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < documentsView.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentDocument = documentsView.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
            if (!string.Equals(
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(currentDocument), ".pdf", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                currentDocument = ConvertToPdf(currentDocument);
            }
            TimeStampPdf(currentDocument);
            Report(new ProgressReport
            {
                Total = documentsView.CheckedItems.Count,
                CurrentCount = i + 1
            });
        }
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Files saved with time-stamp on print script in " + OutputRootPath);
    },
        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
        System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
```

I know that it runs, because the "Files saved with time-stamp on print script in..." message box is displayed.

Comment: I don't see how this even compiles, because `TimeStampPdf` is defined as a void method, and yet you are using its *return value(?)* to call `PerformTask`??

Comment: Also you're not passing a `string` to `TimeStampPdf` when you call it.

Comment: @sstan Sorry, posted the wrong method. I have two that have similar names, and made a careless error in haste. The correct method is now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that even if the condition is false (documentsView.CheckedItemsCount is equal to 0), the task still executes.

That's because your code is starting the `TimeStampPdfs` task here, *before* calling `PerformTask`:

```
await PerformTask(TimeStampPdfs());
```

In other words, `await` does **not** start the task; rather, `TimeStampPdfs` starts the task and returns a task that is already in progress. `await` then (asynchronously) waits for the task to *complete*. You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

If I understand your code correctly, you probably want to pass a *delegate* that returns a task, like this:

```
private async Task PerformTask(Func<Task> func)
{
  if(documentsView.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
  {
    Enabled = false;
    try
    {
      await func();
    }
  ...
}


await PerformTask(() => TimeStampPdfs());
```

On a side note, I recommend using `await` instead of `ContinueWith` for `TimeStampPdfs`:

```
private async Task TimeStampPdfs()
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    ...
  });
  MessageBox.Show("Files saved with time-stamp on print script in " + OutputRootPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.